# How to build a logical argument like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to build a logical argument like this?

[image: 1]

with the color line

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 13):

A simple `array` will do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ r l }
               & p \rightarrow q \\
               & p \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \therefore & q
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

If you want a coloured rule, add [`colortbl`](//ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) to your preamble and use:

[image]

```
\[
  \begin{array}{ r l }
               & p \rightarrow q \\
               & p \\
    \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
    \therefore & q
  \end{array}
\]
```

Rule widths in an `array` can be adjusted using `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{<len>}`. The default is `.4pt`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can you tell me how to increase the thickness of the line?

Comment: To change the thickness you can use `\[\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.75pt} . . .`  for example.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on how much extension you want on the line...two ways are shown.

The thickness of the rule is determined by the value of `\fboxrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
  \alignShortstack{
   & p \rightarrow q\\
   & p\\
   \TABcline{2}
   \therefore & q
  }
\]
\[
  \fboxrule=1pt
  \setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
  \tabbedShortstack[l]{
   & p \rightarrow q&\\
   & p&\\
   \TABcline{2}
   \therefore & q&
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As this question is tagged `tikz-pgf`, I also try to give an answer based on Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}  
\[ \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells] (mat) {& p & \to & q\\
& p & & \\
\therefore & q & & \\ 
};
\draw[red,line width=1pt] ($(mat-2-2.south west)!0.5!(mat-3-2.north west)$)
coordinate (aux) -- (aux-|mat.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is true that this very diagram can be done also with other, arguably more basic packages. On the other hand, at the very moment you wish to do some more fancy things, it is quite possible that you will appreciate the countless features offered by Ti*k*Z.

If you have also commutative diagrams in your document, you may want to use `tikz-cd` anyway, in which case you could simply do

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}  
\[\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture,row sep=3pt,column sep=1pt]
& p \arrow[rr]& ~ & q\\
& p & & \\
\therefore & q & & \\ 
\end{tikzcd}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\draw[red,line width=1pt] ($(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2.south west)!0.5!(\tikzcdmatrixname-3-2.north west)$)
coordinate (aux) -- (aux-|\tikzcdmatrixname.east);
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]